# Find all records older than one year

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection named "listenedMessage" in my MongoDb and it has a field called "timeReceived" 
How do I find all records which are older than one year based on the "timeReceived" field?

Comment: Calculate the date which is exactly one year old in whatever language you are using, and pass it in mongo,

db.test.find({"timeReceived":{$lt: last_year_date} })

Comment: @Puneet thanx a lot. I could create a simple script out of your advice, and its really works now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Puneet Singh's comment I've came to a solution which retrieves all the records having "timeReceived" field older than a particular month.

```
  function addMonths(date, months) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
    return date;
  }

  db.listenedMessage.find({"timeReceived" : {$lt: addMonths(new Date(), -1)}}).count(); //this will give all the records having timeReceived field   older than a month from today
```